# Как в Java нарисовать точку?

Tags: java, графика

Подскажите максимально простой и лаконичный пример, как нарисовать точку с координатами?

Answer (score 5):

Попробуй это

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
g2d.drawOval(5, 5, 100, 100);
```

Comment: сообщает ошибку, нужно создать переменную g

Comment: Спасибо, нарисовалось! Это круг...я думал в ява есть какая то отдельная абстрактная точка, как в математики или физике, поэтому не там искал))

Comment: @user198532, если ответ был правильный - поставьте, пожалуйста, галку напротив ответа.